# How to pass an new props from a parent component with React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is my component's class:

```
import React, { Component }           from 'react';
import {connect}                      from 'react-redux';
import Button                         from '../UI/Button/Button';
import * as actions                   from '../../store/actions';

class Password extends Component {

    submitPassword=(e)=>{   
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.submitPassword(this.state.password, this.props.levelNumber);
    }


    render() {        
        <Button clicked={this.submitPassword} >
            Submit password
        </Button>
    }

}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {

    };
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        submitPassword: (password,levelNumber) =>  dispatch(actions.submitPassword(password,levelNumber))
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Password);
```

and this is my action:

```
export const submitPassword = () => {

    // HERE ALL MY LOGIC !!!

    return {
        level:undefined,
        type:actions.PASSWORD
    }
}
```

The code working all correctly including params and logic.
I wanna that every time that finish to execute the function *submitPassword* A third component refresh/reload with the new props. 
 **Attention! My third component is parent, not child!**
It's possibile to send a command from action to component? How can I do it? 
 I have already tried with:

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
    console.log("new props");
}
```

in my component but he can not take the event.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need always to pass new props for redux state to be accessed.

As redux is having immutable state, you'll always be getting new updated state no matter the previous one. So this will enforce your component to update props to get latest state from redux. This is done by `<Provider>` wrapper attached on root level.

So hence your props will be having new values whenever redux state gets updated.

The lifecycle you are looking is `static getderivedstatefromprops()`. This lifecycle gets executed whenever props are changed/updated.

I made visual implementation on fly that can aid you the picture. Here **Redux State** means **Redux Store**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

normally a structure my redux store as follows

```
{
  entities: {},
  ui: {},
  domain:{}
}
```

so for example when you execute **submitPassword** you execute all the logic and depending on the result you can dispatch another action to update the ui or the domain part so the componentes that are connected respond to those changes.

The UI holds information about UI changes, like if you are submiting info display a progress bar or if it has to display a dialog.

The domain part holds information related to the whole webapp, like loggin info and notifications.

Comment: Could you explain to me with an example how do update the UI?

Comment: when you execute this.props.submitPassword(this.state.password, this.props.levelNumber); an action is dispatched. Where you handle this action, a middleware or a redux-saga named **"asyncHandler"**,  you dispatch another action to indicate that you are submitting a password **isSubmitting(true)** so in a reducer you update the state.ui.login.isSubmitting section and after all the logic in **"asyncHandler"** is executed you dispatch another action **isSubmitting(false)**

In the component you subscribe to the store with connect and provide state.ui.login.isSubmitting as a property